# Obtain lexicographically smallest & largest substring. My algorithm failed most of the test cases but I can't understand why. Help me figure it out

Tags: java, algorithm, lexicographic

I had to do a test today for an interview and the problem was obtaining the lexicographically smallest and largest substring (in other words, sort by name).

> [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U74su.png) - Complete the function SmallestAndLargestSubstring, which takes a string S consisting of lowercase English letters (a-z) as its argument and returns lexicographically smallest and largest substrings which start with a vowel and end with a consonant.

My algorithm passed the basic test cases but failed most of the others. It's not the most efficient code, but it was the fastest to write.

```
static String[] SmallestAndLargestSubstring(String s) {

    ArrayList<Character> vowelList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    vowelList.add('a');
    vowelList.add('e');
    vowelList.add('i');
    vowelList.add('o');
    vowelList.add('u');

    ArrayList<Character> consonantList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char c='a'; c<='z'; c++) {
        if (!vowelList.contains(c))
            consonantList.add(c);
    }

    ArrayList<String> substringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (vowelList.contains(c)) {
            String substring = "";
            substring+=c;
            for (int j=i+1; j<s.length(); j++) {
                char c2 = s.charAt(j);
                substring+=c2;
                if (consonantList.contains(c2)) {
                    substringList.add(substring);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(substringList);

    String[] outputAdapter = new String[2];
    outputAdapter[0]=substringList.get(0);
    outputAdapter[1]=substringList.get(substringList.size()-1);

    return outputAdapter;
}
```

Anyway, I wanted to figure out where I went wrong, so I reversed engineered the test cases to figure out what was the input being passed in, and hopefully I would be able to figure out what was wrong with my algorithm.

Here's what I uncovered, and these are my answers (which are wrong according to the test cases).

> **Input**
>
> String s = "azizezozuzawwwwwwwwwuzzzzzzzzabbbbbbbaaaabbbboiz"
>
> **My answer**
>
> smallest = "aaaab";
>
> largest = "uzzzzzzzzabbbbbbbaaaabbbboiz";

But for the life of me, I can't figure out where my mistake is. Here's my full list of substrings, sorted from the smallest to the largest. [Link to sorted results](http://pastebin.com/VDCXeN1Q)

Been racking my brains for the last 3 hours. I'd be grateful if anyone can figure out where my mistake was.

**Edit: Here are 3 more test cases. My answers match these test case answers.**

> string = "aba"; smallest = "ab"; largest = "ab";
>
> string = "aab"; smallest = "aab"; largest = "ab";
>
> string = "abababababbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaz"; smallest = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaz"; largest = "az";

Comment: The code looks correct to me. For that example, `"aaaab"` and `"uzzzzzzzzabbbbbbbaaaabbbboiz"` are correct.

Comment: I am very interested in learning how you reverse engineered the test cases. :)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the problem isn't supposed to be about subsequences rather than substrings?

Comment: Positive. The first link is a picture to the question. [Link here](http://i.imgur.com/hgxRwtw.png)

Comment: @user2004685: Hmm not sure if I should reveal it so soon as I believe the vulnerability lies with the website used. But the 3rd test case where [string = "abababababbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaz"] was reverse engineered as well, and my answers match the expected answers, so I can confirm that it was done correctly.

Comment: Do you know suffix arrays? With `n=5*10^5`, they probably want you to know them. The naive algorithm is O(n^2) and probably won't pass in most automated judges.

Comment: (The naive algorithm is actually worse than O(n^2), probably more like O(n^3 log n) on worst-case inputs.)

Comment: @Juan Lopes: I understand complexity. The actual code that I submitted has closer to O(n) processing time because 99% of the cases can be checked just using the first character. 

However this isn't the problem here. The program would specifically tell me that it has timed out or ran out of memory when running on very large strings (length>10,000). However this test case is only of size 48 and can be processed quickly using the naive algorithm. It doesn't time out or run out of memory. It simply tells me that my answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
It is the Basic code to Obtain Substring which start with Vowel and End up with Consonant. It is going to print on the Basis of Name Comparable, The first and the Last Substring in the List.Similarly we can achieve on the basis of length, the firt and last Substring using different comparator function.
*/

public class StringSubsequencesStartVowelEndConsonant {
    static List<String> subsequence = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the String:\n");
        String string = in.next();
        findSubstring(string);      
    }

    private static void findSubstring(String string) {      
        for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
            if(isVowel(string.charAt(i))){              
                for(int j=string.length()-1;j>=i;j--){
                    if(isConsonant(string.charAt(j))){                      
                        String subString = string.substring(i,j+1);
                        subsequence.add(subString);
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
        Collections.sort(subsequence);
        for(String str : subsequence){
            System.out.print(str+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(subsequence.get(0));
        System.out.println(subsequence.get(subsequence.size()-1));      
    }
    private static boolean isConsonant(char chars) {
        return !(chars=='a'|| chars=='e'||chars=='i'||chars=='o'||chars=='u');
    }
    private static boolean isVowel(char chars) {
        return (chars=='a'|| chars=='e'||chars=='i'||chars=='o'||chars=='u');
    }
}
```

Comment: Adobe coding written Test Questions .